# Python: Pass Data From One File to Another

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

For example, I have two files, a.py, and b.py. I would like b.py to access data from a.py.

```
#a.py

import random
import subprocess


def rnd():
    return random.random()


random_number_1 = rnd()


if random_number_1 > 0.5:
    subprocess.Popen(['C:/Users/ex/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe', 'b.py'])
```

-

```
#b.py
#get the number generated from a.py and print it.
```

What I would like: Each time a.py is run, a new number is generated. But, each time b.py is run, the same number will be printed, until a.py is run again.

(Python 3.8)

EDIT:
I have seen some similar questions for older versions of Python resolved with pickle and mmap. But I am not familiar with those modules. Could they be helpful? I wasn’t able to get the examples to work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Sounds like you want to save the number to a file. But it depends on why you're doing it

Comment: In this case, you do not pass data from one file to another. You have two processes doing interprocess communication. As @JoelBerkeley said it depends on what you want. Do you want to save this random number? Do you wish to seperate random number generation and saving into two 'modules'? Do you want to have two different Python scripts communicating with each other?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley This case is just an example. I think importing would generate a new number. I would not want a new number.  I think I will need to save it, but, I am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.argv` for that:

```py
#a.py

import random
import subprocess


def rnd():
    return random.random()


random_number_1 = rnd()


if random_number_1 > 0.5:
    subprocess.Popen(['C:/Users/ex/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe', 'b.py', str(random_number_1)])
```

And in b.py you can access that number:

```
#b.py
import sys
random_number_1 = float(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[1])
```

So what is `sys.argv`? For example when you write that in command prompt:

```
C:\> pip install my_module
```

In pip program it access to "install" and "my_module" like that:

```
import sys
sys.argv[0] # full path of program (for example C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe)
sys.argv[1] # "install"
sys.argv[2] # "my_module"
```

In this way you can only pass that number for one time, it will not change in b.py if you change it in a.py. Also if you want you can write that number to a file:

```
#a.py

import random
import subprocess
import pickle

def rnd():
    return random.random()


random_number_1 = rnd()

with open("C:\\data.txt","wb") as f:
    f.write(pickle.dumps(random_number_1))


if random_number_1 > 0.5:
    subprocess.Popen(['C:/Users/ex/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe', 'b.py'])
```

And in b.py you can read that file:

```
#b.py
import pickle
with open("C:\\data.txt","rb") as f:
    random_number_1 = pickle.load(f)
print(random_number_1)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, when I run a.py. But, it returns an error message when I run just b.py.

Comment: Yes. What you want to be when b.py run alone?

Comment: What I would like: Each time a.py is run, a new number is generated. But, each time b.py is run, the same number will be printed, until a.py is run again.

Comment: So why you use subprocess in a.py to open b.py if you will run b.py alone sometimes? You should write that number to an file. I will update my answer.

Comment: “So why you use subprocess in a.py to open b.py if you will run b.py alone sometimes?” This is a simplified example. “a.py” is really for placing an order. “random_number_1” is the unique Order ID. “b.py” will be used to make API calls to check the status of the order with the Order ID.

Comment: Thank you, for your help. Your updated answer is the solution.